# How to hide shape in the stage，but displayed on rect

Tags: konvajs, konva, konvajs-reactjs

As in the picture, this is an effect on the line   [online](https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/polotno-project/polotno-site/tree/source/examples/polotno-demo?fontsize=11&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&view=preview)

Please give me an idea[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsscf.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I created a responsive rect as an artboard in the stage, and when I add shapes and move them, I want the shapes to only show on the rect, just like opening a window on the stage, only show the shapes inside the window